# How can I ensure HGFS in CentOS via Vagrant?

Tags: centos, vagrant, vmware-fusion

I am using Vagrant (1.7.4) with the VMware Fusion provider.

I have created a new VM from the centos/7 box, and configured shared folders in my Vagrantfile.

On startup, I get the message

> HGFS was never found on the running virtual machine. This must be
>   installed either through VMware tools or Open VM Tools. HGFS is
>   required for shared folders to work properly. Please install either
>   the VMware tools or Open VM Tools and try again.

after a while, and the system starts up, but without the mounted shared volume.

I have tried installing Open VM tools, with a

```
sudo yum -y install open-vm-tools
```

in my Vagrant provisioner inline shell script

```
 config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    sudo yum -y update
    sudo yum -y install open-vm-tools
 SHELL
```

However, I still get the message at startup, and I do not see the mounted share.

I have an almost identical Ubuntu box (precise/64) that seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the box https://atlas.hashicorp.com/centos/boxes/7 and from the [release notes](https://seven.centos.org/2016/09/updated-centos-vagrant-images-available-v1608-01/) they clearly mention that virtual box guest are not installed

> The VirtualBox Guest Additions are not preinstalled; if you need them for shared folders, please install the vagrant-vbguest plugin. We recommend using NFS instead of VirtualBox shared folders if possible.

I think what they should mention is that they did not install the VMWare tools neither so default sharing folder with VMWare does not work.

## How to install the VMWare tools for the VM

1. Make sure to mount a cd

Open VMWare Fusion and make sure the VM is down - open the VM settings, select the hard drive and add a device, select the CDRom.

boot the VM from the VM menu select *Install VMWare Tools*

2. Installing VMWare Tools

login to the VM (either from VMWare or open an ssh session with `vagrant ssh`)

3. Install pre-requisites and update kernel (at least I had to run to successfully install the VMWare tools on VMWare fusion 8.0 - see [here](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2016514))

   ```
   sudo yum install perl gcc gcc-c++ make binutils
   sudo yum update kernel
   ```

reboot and run the following again

```
sudo yum install kernel-headers kernel-PAE-devel
```

4. mount the VMWare tools

this is found from the [VMWare doc](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018414) - Make sure to run the below commands with `root` or add `sudo`

To create a mount point, run:

```
mkdir /mnt/cdrom
```

To mount the CDROM, run:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```

To copy the Compiler gzip tar file to a temporary local directory, run:

```
cp /mnt/cdrom/VMwareTools-<version>.tar.gz /tmp/
```

Where version is the VMware Tools package version. To determine the version of VMware tools, run:

```
ls /mnt/cdrom
```

You see output similar to:

```
VMwareTools-5.0.0-12124.tar.gz
```

To change to the tmp directory and extract the contents of the tar file into a new directory called vmware-tools-distrib, run:

```
cd /tmp
tar -zxvf VMwareTools-version.tar.gz
```

To change directory to vmware-tools-distrib and run the `vmware-install.pl` PERL script to install VMware Tools, run:

```
cd vmware-tools-distrib
./vmware-install.pl
```

After all this, the tools were installed and shared folder is working correctly.

as a side note I can say that its much easier building a box with [packer](http://www.packer.io) and install the tools directly from install. There are plenty of packer templates available on github for all versions of centos.

Comment: I am using hashicorp's centos/7 box